# Exception: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, one-to-many

I am trying to do one to many relations (table EmployeeEntity and  AddressEntity),but when i build i get errors.

AddressEntity class

```
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = "eeEntity")

public class AddressEntity {
..

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "addressEntity", targetEntity = com.howtodoinjava.demo.model.AddressEntity.class,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)

private Set<EmployeeEntity> eeEntity;

public AddressEntity(String city, EmployeeEntity... eeEntity) {
    this.city = city;
    this.eeEntity = Stream.of(eeEntity).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    this.eeEntity.forEach(x -> x.setAddressEntity(this));
}
---------
```

EmployeeEntity class

```
@Data
@Entity
public class EmployeeEntity {
...
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = com.howtodoinjava.demo.model.AddressEntity.class)
private AddressEntity addressEntity;

public AddressEntity getAddressEntity() {
    return addressEntity;
}

public void setAddressEntity(AddressEntity addressEntity) {
    this.addressEntity = addressEntity;
```

---

Error: 
2020-01-17 00:01:24.401  WARN 4890 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.howtodoinjava.demo.model.AddressEntity.addressEntity in com.howtodoinjava.demo.model.AddressEntity.eeEntity

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.howtodoinjava.demo.model.AddressEntity.addressEntity in com.howtodoinjava.demo.model.AddressEntity.eeEntity

Can someone help me understand why I get this?

Comment: you are missing @Entity annotation on AddressEntity class

Comment: I tried that also but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code snippet,

In AddressEntity class,

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "addressEntity", targetEntity = com.howtodoinjava.demo.model.AddressEntity.class,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<EmployeeEntity> eeEntity;
```

In EmployeeEntity class,

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="ADDRESS_ID", nullable=false)
private AddressEntity addressEntity;
```

where ADDRESS_ID can be primary key of AddressEntity.